# Redirect to Https exclude subdomains but regardless of WWW or not

Tags: .htaccess

I haven't seen this specific question on here but I'd like to know how to redirect the main site I have, regardless of whether someone includes "www" in the URL, but not redirect any subdomains. How do I do it?

This is what I have but it only works if they add the "www".

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.example.com
RewriteRule (.*)  https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this rule to redirect main domain with or without `www`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

`^(?:www\.)?` matches optional `www` at the start.